# How to force light-server not to open browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, worklight-server

This is the `package.json` of my project, when I tried to run `npm start`. I tried setting parameters `--no-open` or `--no-browser` or `open:false`

```
 {
      "dependencies": {
        "kekule": "^1.0.0"
      },
      "name": "pca",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "index.js",
      "devDependencies": {
        "lite-server": "^2.6.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "lite-server --no-browser"
      },
    
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "description": ""
    }
```

All the above solutions never work and `npm start` command invoke the server and opens up a browser window. how to stop that?

Comment: How did you use `open: false`? It should work.